# Testing a simple linked list, but it insists on iterating backwards

Tags: c++, linked-list

I made a simple linked list to see if I understand them completely, and I am currently trying to verify that all of the data points are in the proper places. They are not, but I'm not sure why. I THINK that the problem is in one of two areas.
It's either an error in the construction of the list or else there is something wrong with the way I'm attempting to output the data.

```
//////////////
//linkedlist.h
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H
namespace LinkedListMagno
{
    class LinkList
    {
    public:
        LinkList(int theData, LinkList* thePoint) : data(theData), point(thePoint){};
        int getData() {return data;}
        void setData(int theData) {data = theData;}
        LinkList* getLink() {return point;}
        void setLink(LinkList* thePoint) {point = thePoint;}
    private:
        int data;
        LinkList* point;
    };
}//LinkedListMagno
#endif



    ////////////
    //source.cpp
    #include<iostream>
    #include "linkedlist.h"
    using LinkedListMagno::LinkList;
    using std::cin;
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;

    LinkList* getListPtr(int data[], int lenOfData);
    //precondition: passed an array of integers and the length of the same array
    //postcondition: returns a pointer to a linked list containing the integers from data[] in the given order



    int main()
    {
        LinkList *head, *point;
        int data[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};//these numbers will go into the list in ascending order
        int len = 10;

        head = getListPtr(data, len);
        point = head;

        for(int i=0; i<len; i++)//Pretty sure the problem is here. How on earth is it iterating backwards through the list?
        {
            cout << point->getData();
            point = point->getLink();
        }

        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }

    LinkList* getListPtr(int data[], int lenOfData)
    {
        LinkList *head, *newPoint; //two pointers. One for the head, the other to add nodes

        for(int i=0; i<lenOfData; i++)
        {
            if(i == 0)
            {
                head = new LinkList(data[i], NULL);//create new linklist object using the first data point
                cout << "New Node: " << data[i] << endl;
                newPoint = head;//for the first node, set newPoint equal to the head
            }
            else if(i>0 && i<lenOfData)
            {
                newPoint->setLink(new LinkList(data[i], newPoint->getLink()));
                cout << "New Node: " << data[i] << endl;
                //newPoint = newPoint->getLink(); Derp. Forgot to add this line.
                //for each item in data[], add a new node and move newPoint* to the new location
            }
        }

        return head;
    }
```

Expected output:

```
New Node: 0
New Node: 1
New Node: 2
New Node: 3
New Node: 4
New Node: 5
New Node: 6
New Node: 7
New Node: 8
New Node: 9
0123456789Press any key to continue . . .
```

Actual output:

```
New Node: 0
New Node: 1
New Node: 2
New Node: 3
New Node: 4
New Node: 5
New Node: 6
New Node: 7
New Node: 8
New Node: 9
0987654321Press any key to continue . . . (WTF?)
```

I don't understand. It can't be iterating backwards through the list, can it? Singly linked lists don't work that way. The only thing I can think of is that the links themselves are out of order, but I don't see any problem with the method I used.
What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a quick scan through the code, you are not moving your newPoint pointer on as you add new nodes in getListPtr. So each new node is added directly after head since newPoint is initialized to head and remains there.

Comment: Oh jeeze. Are you serious?
Yeah, that's what I forgot. Thanks a lot, Chris. It works exactly as intended now.